# How to change a rectangle's position and size realtime?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, real-time

I want to draw an  rectangle and  can change the rectangle's position and size realtime.

I have tried following two methods, but the view don't show the rectangle.

do you have any advice or example?

appreciate your help.

**use view frame** (it only show the new rectangle when restart the app)

```
UIView * drawView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];
[self.view addSubview:drawView];
drawView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor orangeColor] CGColor];
drawView.layer.borderWidth = 2;

drawView.frame = CGRectMake(r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height);
```

**draw in the drawRect**

```
fav = [[FaceAugmentingView alloc] initWithFrame:[imageView frame]];
fav.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview: fav  ];
fav.face = CGRectMake(r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height);
[fav setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: We can't help if you don't tell us which language/dev environment you're using.

Comment: It's tagged iphone - which means Xcode/Objective-C/Cocoa-Touch in *most* cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you add a method that reloads the faces based whenever you need to alter it. Declare and array that will help us keep track of all the views we've added.

```
@interface FacesViewController: UIViewController
[..]
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray * faceViews;

- (void)reloadFaces;
[..]
@end
```

And then implement `reloadFaces` something like this -

```
- (void)reloadFaces {
    /* remove all current views we've added */
    for ( UIView * aView in self.faceViews ) {
        [aView removeFromSuperview];
    }
    [self.faceViews removeAllObjects];

    /* Add news ones */
    int numberOfFaces = [self numberOfFacesInImage];
    for ( int i = 0; i < numberOfFaces; i++ ) {
        CGRect faceFrame = [self frameForFaceAtIndex:i];

        UIView * drawView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:faceFrame] autorelease];
        drawView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor orangeColor] CGColor];
        drawView.layer.borderWidth = 2;
        drawView.frame = CGRectMake(r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height);

        [self.view addSubview:drawView];
        [faceViews addObject:drawView];
    }
}
```

I would expect `reloadFaces` to be called when there is a change of some kind. `numberOfFacesInImage` and `frameForFaceAtIndex:` are methods that you will have to implement based on how you get the data. You can also replace them to suit your data model. Don't forget to initialize `faceViews`.

Comment: I have tried both methods, but the view don't show the rectangle

Comment: By realtime you mean you want it to follow touches?

Comment: not follow touches. when I detect one face, I want to draw a rectangle around the face. For your first method, only when I restart the app, it will display the view, then it will not change. I need to restart the app again to let its new frame available. do you have any advice? appreciate for your help

Comment: it seems available, I have tried again, but it is the same as using view frame. the view only show the new rectangle only when restart the app. I am confused, why? I have remove and re-add the drawview with new frame.

Comment: Yeah! but that was because you were adding the frame only at the beginning and did not change it later.

Comment: Because the view won't automatically change its frame. You will have to track what the new frame is and then set the view's frame to that in realtime. Assuming that there might be many faces (rather than one), my example is tracking all the faces in the image.

Comment: I have changed the frame, when I detect a moving face.

Comment: in my code, there is a sublayer in view:      avLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:session];
    avLayer.frame = [imageView  frame]; 
    [self.view.layer addSublayer: avLayer];
    avLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;

Comment: does it a matter(AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer)?

Comment: Which third party library are you using?

Comment: when I do detect, I use opencv